# What's the use of chords?

Tags: c#, .net, nemerle, chord

Languages such as Nemerle support the idea of chords. I'd like to know what their practical use is.

Comment: I can see why you ask this question. Googling for "c#", "chord", etc. really isn't very helpful!

Comment: Well C# doesn't support chords, the Polyphonic version did, but I think that language no longer exists, right?

Answer (score 2):

The construct also seems to exist in the [Cω](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%CF%89) language (as well as Polyphonic C#), at least according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(concurrency).

The primary usage of *chords* appears to involve database programming (more specifically, [join calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_calculus)), which is unsurprising given that it is a concurrency construct. More than that, I'm afraid I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

A chord is used for concurrency.  The definition is available [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/comega/doc/comega_whatis.htm).

The bit you are looking for:

> In most languages, including C#, methods in the signature of a class are in bijective correspondence with the code of their implementations -- for each method which is declared, there is a single, distinct definition of what happens when that method is called. In Cω, however, a body may be associated with a set of (synchronous and/or asynchronous) methods. We call such a definition a chord, and a particular method may appear in the header of several chords. The body of a chord can only execute once all the methods in its header have been called. Thus, when a method is called there may be zero, one, or more chords which are enabled:
>
> If no chord is enabled then the method
>   invocation is queued up. If the method
>   is asynchronous, then this simply
>   involves adding the arguments (the
>   contents of the message) to a queue.
>   If the method is synchronous, then the
>   calling thread is blocked.  If there
>   is a single enabled chord, then the
>   arguments of the calls involved in the
>   match are de-queued, any blocked
>   thread involved in the match is
>   awakened, and the body runs.  When a
>   chord which involves only asynchronous
>   methods runs, then it does so in a new
>   thread.  If there are several chords
>   which are enabled then an unspecified
>   one of them is chosen to run. 
>   Similarly, if there are multiple calls
>   to a particular method queued up, we
>   do not specify which call will be
>   de-queued when there is a match.

Answer (score 2):

Try Nemerle Computation Expressions:

https://code.google.com/p/nemerle/source/browse/nemerle/trunk/snippets/ComputationExpressions/

Some examples:

```
 def upTo (n : int)
  {
    comp enumerable
    {
      mutable i = 0;
      while (i < n)
      {
        i ++;
        yield i
      }
    }
  }

  def manyTimes : IEnumerable [int] =
    comp enumerable
    {
      yieldcomp upTo(2);   // 1 2
      yield 100;           // 100
      yieldcomp upTo(3);   // 1 2 3
      yield 100;           // 100
      yieldcomp upTo(10);  // 1 2 3 .. 10
    }
```

---

```
def fn(n)
  {
    comp async
    {
      if (n < 20)
        returncomp fn(n + 1);
      else
        return n;
    }
  }
  def f(n1, n2)
  {
    comp async
    {
      defcomp n1 = fn(n1);
      defcomp n2 = fn(n2);
      return $"$n1 $n2";
    }
  }
```

---

```
private HttpGet(url : string) : Async[string]
{
  comp async
  {
    def req = WebRequest.Create(url);
    using (defcomp resp = req.AsyncGetResponse())
    using (stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
    using (reader = StreamReader(stream))
      return reader.ReadToEnd();
  }
}
```

Some more examples here: (Although article in Russian but code in English :) ) http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/programming/108184/